# How to show list of years in xslt 2.0?

Tags: javascript, xslt-2.0

I am new in xslt and javascript.
I have shown current date in input field using xslt 2.0

```
<input id="date" type="date" class="input">
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(),
                      '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </input>
```

but now I want to show year list in dropdown, years should be current year with back 10 years for e.g. [2018,2017,2016,..] like this

but I am not able to generate years array dynamically, I think we can do this using .js please help me to implement this.

Currently I am showing years from xml file like this.

```
<select  class="select">
                        <xsl:for-each select="element/year/option">
                            <option value="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></option>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </select>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using XSLT 2 or 3 (as the tag and the example suggests) you use code like

```
      <xsl:variable name="current-year" as="xs:integer" select="year-from-date(current-date())"/>
      <select name="year">
          <xsl:for-each select="reverse($current-year - 9 to $current-year)">
              <option value="{.}">{.}</option>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
```

e.g. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CT outputs

```
<select name="year">
         <option value="2018">2018</option>
         <option value="2017">2017</option>
         <option value="2016">2016</option>
         <option value="2015">2015</option>
         <option value="2014">2014</option>
         <option value="2013">2013</option>
         <option value="2012">2012</option>
         <option value="2011">2011</option>
         <option value="2010">2010</option>
         <option value="2009">2009</option></select>
```

That examples uses text value template of XSLT 3 but in XSLT 2 you would use `<option value="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></option>` instead.